# Sparql request to Wikidata with subquery leads to timeout

Tags: subquery, sparql, wikidata

It might be because of a wrong understanding of how selects with subqueries work, but I encounter the following problem.
The following query should provide all the labels of a sub list of items (having occupation mathematician) limited by an explicit limit:

```
SELECT ?item ?label
WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label ?labelNode .
  {
  SELECT ?item
      WHERE
        { ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q170790. }
  LIMIT 3
  }
 BIND(STR(?labelNode) AS ?label).
}
```

I had understood from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#subqueries) that the subquery should be evaluated first, providing 3 items to the outer scope, where then all labels will be retrieve. 
The inner query does indeed its job in 1 second. But the full query leads to time out.
Is it a problem in wikidata? do I wrongly understand the concept of subquery?

Comment: https://w.wiki/5Sz

Comment: Thanks for the hint about "hints" ... Are these standard SPARQL specifications? or only valid for wikidata?

Comment: They are Blazegrapg-specific, see https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints and  https://wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization